# How to chain http calls with superagent/supertest?

Tags: node.js, express, supertest, superagent

I am testing an express API with supertest.

I couldn't get multiple requests in a test case to work with supertest. Below is what i tried in a test case. But the test case seem to only execute the last call which is the HTTP GET.

```
it('should respond to GET with added items', function(done) {
    var agent = request(app);
    agent.post('/player').type('json').send({name:"Messi"});
    agent.post('/player').type('json').send({name:"Maradona"});
    agent.get('/player').set("Accept", "application/json")
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            res.body.should.have.property('items').with.lengthOf(2);
            done();
    });
);
```

Anything i am missing here, or is there another way to chain http calls with superagent?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The calls are made asynchronous, so you need to use callback functions to chain them.

```
it('should respond to GET with added items', function(done) {
    var agent = request(app);
    agent.post('/player').type('json').send({name:"Messi"}).end(function(){
        agent.post('/player').type('json').send({name:"Maradona"}).end(function(){
            agent.get('/player')
                .set("Accept", "application/json")
                .expect(200)
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    res.body.should.have.property('items').with.lengthOf(2);
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have a look at [supertest-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.org/package/supertest-as-promised) to reduce the nesting of callbacks

Comment: Is it possible to chain them without using `mocha` or `it` ?

Comment: supertest has native promise support since version [2.0.0](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/master/History.md#200--2016-07-29)

Comment: I couldn't get this solution to work. However, I could get the "async" solution (by Tim) below to work.

Comment: This answer is correct, however outdated, using async/await can give the same result with a much cleaner implementation

Comment: @ricca The link you've added to multiple posts does not work anymore.

Answer (score 69):

Tried to put this in a comment above, formatting wasn't working out.

I'm using async, which is **really** standard and works really well.

```
it('should respond to only certain methods', function(done) {
    async.series([
        function(cb) { request(app).get('/').expect(404, cb); },
        function(cb) { request(app).get('/new').expect(200, cb); },
        function(cb) { request(app).post('/').send({prop1: 'new'}).expect(404, cb); },
        function(cb) { request(app).get('/0').expect(200, cb); },
        function(cb) { request(app).get('/0/edit').expect(404, cb); },
        function(cb) { request(app).put('/0').send({prop1: 'new value'}).expect(404, cb); },
        function(cb) { request(app).delete('/0').expect(404, cb); },
    ], done);
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Async works fantastically in this context.

Comment: Great approach! I extended it somewhat, check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45198533/449227

Comment: I get "cannot find name async". Is there a package needed for this? I can't seem to find an answer online

Answer (score 15):

This can be most elegantly solved with promises, and there's a really useful library to use promises with supertest: https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest-as-promised

Their example:

```
return request(app)
  .get("/user")
  .expect(200)
  .then(function (res) {
    return request(app)
      .post("/kittens")
      .send({ userId: res})
      .expect(201);
  })
  .then(function (res) {
    // ... 
  });
```

Comment: Promises are a good option here. Just need to be weary of situations where you might need to recover from a 404 somewhere in that chain.

Comment: supertest has native promise support since version [2.0.0](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/master/History.md#200--2016-07-29)

Answer (score 9):

I built upon [Tim’s reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25945659/449227) but used `async.waterfall` instead, to be able to do assert tests on the results (note: I use [Tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) here instead of Mocha):

```
test('Test the entire API', function (assert) {
    const app = require('../app/app');
    async.waterfall([
            (cb) => request(app).get('/api/accounts').expect(200, cb),
            (results, cb) => { assert.ok(results.body.length, 'Returned accounts list'); cb(null, results); },
            (results, cb) => { assert.ok(results.body[0].reference, 'account #0 has reference'); cb(null, results); },
            (results, cb) => request(app).get('/api/plans').expect(200, cb),
            (results, cb) => request(app).get('/api/services').expect(200, cb),
            (results, cb) => request(app).get('/api/users').expect(200, cb),
        ],
        (err, results) => {
            app.closeDatabase();
            assert.end();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of time. Currently, it's the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```js
const agent = request(server.app);
const fn = (counter) => {
  agent.get('/').end((_error, res) => {
    if (res.status !== 200) {
      done();
      expect(counter).toEqual(20);
    } else
      fn(counter + 1);
  })
}

fn(1);
```