# Chaining requests with Superagent without Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, superagent

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089842/how-to-chain-http-calls-with-superagent-supertest) talks about chaining requests but it is using `mocha`.

How can I chain `superagent` requests (calling another rest API in the end method) without using `Mocha` or `it`?

When I do the chaining

```
superagent.post( URL ).send( DATA ).end( function(err,res){
  console.log("1");
  superagent.post( URL1 ).send( DATA1 ).end( function(err,res){
    console.log("2");
  });
});
```

Neither of the console.log is seen on the console.

Comment: I don't actually believe you that the first console.log won't appear.

Comment: @djechlin well today it is not working without nesting also (remeber prev question?) URLs are reachable through browser though and I am getting a response.

Comment: @gurvinder372 did you ever get around this? I'm at the point where the first console log will trigger, but the second won't